# Why doesn't {in love with} fit in the sentence: When I was a teenager, I fell _____ this Italian guy

Tags: idioms, prepositions, vocabulary

My answer was {in love with} but it was marked wrong.

Yet Cambridge Dictionary uses a very similar example in their entry for [**fall in love**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-in-love)

- *He fell in love with a young German student*

Can anyone fill the gap and explain why theirs is the correct solution
but mine {in love with} isn't?

> When I was a teenager, I fell _____ this Italian guy. I was so in love that I spent all my money on a ticket to Rome

P.S This is not a request to proofread, I have clearly identified the problem that is making me confused.

Comment: Did the quiz not allow you to see the right answer? Anyway, if you hyphenate _head-over-heels_ and follow it with the correct preposition, you have an answer that fits.

Comment: Are there two words missing, as it seems, or is there no word limit?

Comment: Second word is likely *for*, with any modifier—hard, stupidly, passionately, etc.

Comment: @Mari-Lou  no limit, I miss typing the space on the line, already fixed.

Comment: I would just say "fell for this Italian guy".

Comment: Welcome. Could you describe the correct answer or give us a hint why yours was rejected? Thanks

Comment: @Elliot I did not have the answer, but I got a wrong for the answer I provide.

Comment: @nelLuffy, the only obvious explanation is that the blank line represents a single missing word - and that word is "for". If you can use multiple words to fill the blank, then there are a variety of other idioms that would fit the bill, including "in love with".

Comment: So far as the ordinary English usage is concerned, your answer is OK. Why your answer was nevertheless marked as wrong is a question that you should address to whomever has so marked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I was a teenager, I fell **head over heels with/for** this Italian guy. I was so in love that I spent all my money on a ticket to Rome

To fall [**head over heels** (in love)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/head%20over%20heels) **with** or **for** someone is a common-day English expression which Merriam-Webster says is also an adverb. It means to be so much in love that you are prepared to do crazy things such as spending all your spare cash on a one-way ticket to Rome. In other words, the person's life is figuratively turned upside down.

Vocabulary.com has a good description and explanation

> When you're *head over heels*, you're confused or thrown off by something. People say they're head over heels in love when they feel disoriented and swept up by their romantic feelings.

> You can use *head over heels* for a particular state of disarray, although it usually shows up in the context of love, and it's come to mean something closer to "extremely." Your parents are lucky to be head over heels in love after being married more than twenty years. [The original phrase was "heels over head," which makes sense, since our heads are normally over our heels.](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/head%20over%20heels) For some reason, it was reversed to *head over heels* in the eighteenth century.

Comment: Can you explain why I got wrong,  what problem in my answer

Comment: @nelLuffy  Your [solution fits](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fall-in-love), but it lacks that element of obsession that one feels when someone is "madly" or "head over heels" in love. It could be that the answer the tester was looking for was an idiom (my solution), or simply a preposition ("for" was suggested in the comments). Were there no other instructions in the question? Maybe the answer was simply "I fell for him" i.e. I was infatuated. In the end, you'll have to ask your teacher.

Comment: I’ve never heard “head over heels ***with***”.

Comment: I see [it’s used though:](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22head%20over%20heels%20with%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2009,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en).  Still sounds wrong to me though.

Comment: The test that the OP took was apparently of the kind in which answers are marked as correct or incorrect; it was not an open-ended, essay-type test. How was a candidate taking this test supposed to know that this is **the one and only** correct answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

What is probably asked is a collocative combination. "**to fall madly for**" is a common one. ([ref](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=15&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&content=fell+madly+for%2C+fell+head-over-heel+for&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfell%20madly%20for%3B%2Cc0))

Comment: The question has been edited, and as a result I have deleted my old comments.

Comment: @jsw My answer is far from a claim of the locution I mention being **the** correct possibility ("is **a** common one"); although "head over heels" is much more collocative, "madly" **is** collocative and provides a reasonable solution:https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=15&year_end=2008&year_start=1800&content=fell+head-over-heels+for%2Cfell+head+over+heels+for%2Cfell+madly+for&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfell%20head%20over%20heels%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfell%20madly%20for%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfell%20head%20over%20heels%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfell%20madly%20for%3B%2Cc0.

Comment: @jsw29 Initially, what you had was two segments ( "____ ________", not "__________", which is what you find now, there has been an edition of the post), and that, for one thing implied two terms.